# Error in connecting with Spark using spark_connect command in 'sparklyr': (R-3.4.0)

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I have Spark 1.6.2 installed on my system. Also I am using R(3.4.0) with rstudio-server 1.0.143 in CentOS 6.9 machine.

Whenever I am running the command,

> sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

it shows an error message stating that:

> Error in spark_version_from_home(spark_home, default = spark_version)
>   :    Failed to detect version from SPARK_HOME or SPARK_HOME_VERSION.
>   Try passing the spark version explicitly.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You'll need to specify your SPARK_HOME manually, sparklyr has sometimes troubles detecting it from the system.

Comment: @halfer I am meeting a deadline which is why I added the phrase 'as soon as possible'. I have full respect for this forum but I personally do not think that using these phrases should be done away with. Everyone needs answers in the shortest possible time. So do I. Anyways, I will take of this next time. Also, thank you for informing me about this. :)